# Why the mesh is twisting when base bone is rotated?

Tags: rigging

I am trying to rig long year of dog.

1. It needs to bend along chain of bones
2. And its base bone should be able to rotate the whole ear without twist.

> I understand why there is deformation but i need to understand why there is twist in whole ear when only base bone is rotated

[image]

[image]

Please check this [EAR Rig File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jpq2cgNh8zRlBnbVJNaHJERHM/view?usp=sharing) and help me with twist.

Answer (score 1):

That deformation occurs because you didn't add weights in [weight paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html#introduction) mode.

- Select the armature and change to *pose mode*
- In pose mode with the armature selected click the mesh
- Change to *weight paint mode*
- Select bone by bone and add vertex weight

[image]

Related:

[Vertex Weight Issues](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28676/vertex-weight-issues)

Comment: I understand why there is deformation but i need to understand why there is twist in whole ear when only base bone is rotated

Answer (score 1):

You have two sets of bones **DEF** and **MCH** , **MCH** inherit the rotation from the root bone , while the **DEF** bones copy the location and the orientation of **MCH** but they keep their own rotation ( **DEF** bones are the ones controlling the mesh ) when you rotate the root or one of the **MCH** bones the DEF will follow but maintain its rotation ( which seems like the twisting effect )

A quick solution is to choose the first **DEF** bone and parented to the first **MCH** bone ( also check inherit rotation )

Comment: @ashwin does this answer your question ?